# asp.net mvc4 ajax action link

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Good day for everyone,

I have an asp.net mvc4 project which include ajax action link. And I'm a little confused, when try to send the Id value, I will try next tricks:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click", "StudentEdit" + "/" + Model.StudentId, new AjaxOptions
                                               {
                                                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                   LoadingElementId = "progress"
                                               })
```

And next:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click", "StudentEdit", new AjaxOptions
                                               {
                                                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                   LoadingElementId = "progress"
                                               }, new {id = Model.StudentId})
```

For the first time it's send only request to the `ControllerName/StudentEdit`

And the second time I have an error in my VS2012: `Cannot resolve method 'ActionLink' candidates next`.

The question is next: How can I send my Model.StudentId property into the my ActionLink edit method?

P.S.: I have GET StudentEdit() and POST StudentEdit(int id)

Comment: Actually you're setting the actionlink id to Model.StudentId, place it before your ajaxoptions and it may work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Click", "StudentEdit", new {id = Model.StudentId}, new AjaxOptions
                                           {
                                               HttpMethod = "POST",
                                               LoadingElementId = "progress"
                                           }
```

You have your arguments out of order ... it goes:

1. Link Text
2. Action
3. Route Values
4. Ajax Options

Here are all the [Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overloads.